# Trigger en PL-SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de evitar una inserción de datos mediante un trigger.
Tengo el siguiente código, tengo un objeto que puede ser prestado en caso de estar disponible (estado=2)
sin embargo, cuando el estado del objeto es ocupado (estado = 1) no debería poderse insertar datos en la tabla préstamo.
Este es mi código

```
create or replace TRIGGER insertar_prestamo
BEFORE INSERT ON PRESTAMO
FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
    estado number;
BEGIN
SELECT OBJETO.cod_estado INTO estado FROM OBJETO
       WHERE OBJETO.cod_objeto=:NEW.cod_objeto;
IF(estado=2) THEN
   UPDATE OBJETO
    set cod_estado= 1
    WHERE 
      OBJETO.cod_objeto=:NEW.cod_objeto;
ELSE
    raise_application_error(-20600,estado||'No se puede insertar');
END IF;
END;​
```

Al ejecutarlo me sale lo siguiente:
ORA-20600: 1No se puede insertar
ORA-06512: at "PROYECTO.INSERTAR_PRESTAMO", line 12
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'PROYECTO.INSERTAR_PRESTAMO'

Alguien sabe como podría evitar la inserción si el objeto no esta disponible?

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido bien tu problema, se solucionaría accediendo directamente a `cod_estado`. Quedaría algo así:

```
create or replace TRIGGER insertar_prestamo
BEFORE INSERT ON PRESTAMO
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

BEGIN

    IF(:NEW.cod_estado = 2) THEN
        UPDATE OBJETO
        set cod_estado= 1
        WHERE 
        OBJETO.cod_objeto=:NEW.cod_objeto;
    ELSE
        raise_application_error(-20600,estado||'No se puede insertar');
    END IF;
END;​
```